# React 0.14.0-RC1 / React-Router 1.0.0-RC1 - Cannot read property 'props' of null

Tags: socket.io, reactjs, react-router

> I am working off **Alex Bank's ["Building a Polling App with Socket IO](http://www.lynda.com/Developer-Web-Development-tutorials/Building-Polling-App-Socket-IO-React-js/387145-2.html)**
>   **and React.js" (Lynda.com)**, but I am trying to upgrade it to
>   react-router 1.0.0-RC1.

---

> My [**github repository can be found here ....**](https://github.com/SarasotaSun/koa-react-isomorphic-io-mongo-passport-master)

**Problem:**

When a speaker signs in and creates a presentation, a list of questions successful appears. However, when the speaker clicks on a respective question to emit to the attendees, I receive the error: **"Cannot read property 'props' of null"** which identifies the error in the Question.js component:

```
ask(question) {
  console.log('this question: ' + JSON.stringify(question));
  this.props.emit('ask', question); <--- Console points to this
}
```

But I do not believe that is the problem per se. I believe the actual problem is that this emit is not reaching the socket.on in the app.

**APP.js:**

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  this.socket.on('ask', this.ask.bind(this));
  ....
}

ask(question) {
  sessionStorage.answer = '';
  this.setState({ currentQuestion: question });
}
```

I **believe** it is react-router related, but the parent route does have component {APP}, and Speaker is a child route and the Speaker component does import the Question component, so I am assuming the Question component is connected to the APP's.

In Alex's project it is working, but he uses:

```
  "react": "^0.13.3",
  "react-router": "^0.13.3",
```

Any chance someone can offer me some insight on this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If your error says "Cannot read property 'props' of null," that's exactly what's happening: you're attemping to call `.props` on a value that is `null`.

However, the real problem is in this code:

```javascript
ask(question) {
  console.log('this question: ' + JSON.stringify(question));
  this.props.emit('ask', question);
}

addQuestion(question, index) {
  return (
    <div key={ index } className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <span onClick={ this.ask.bind(null, question) }>{ question.q }</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Specifically, [this code](https://github.com/SarasotaSun/koa-react-isomorphic-io-mongo-passport-master/blob/9742f99bca5878fa0c465481acde1abb9e3f0e02/src/components/parts/Questions.js#L22) (which isn't included in the question):

```javascript
onClick={ this.ask.bind(null, question) }>
```

You're assigning a click handler to a version of `this.ask` that's bound to `null`; this works fine with `React.createClass`-type components, because React forcibly and automatically binds all component methods to the component instance, no matter what you pass as the first argument to `.bind()` (and so `null` is commonly used; I think React actually yells at you otherwise). However, this is not the case with ES6 classes; you're literally setting `this` inside `ask()` to `null`.

A correct version would be

```javascript
onClick={ this.ask.bind(this, question) }>
```

or, commonly, as an anonymous function

```javascript
onClick={ () => this.ask(question) }>
```

Comment: Making the change as you recommended (I even pushed it to github), I get a new error, "this.props.emit is not a function", apparently related to the APP's mapping (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983880/reactjs-this-props-is-not-a-function-when-child-component-calls-parent)

Comment: @SarasotaSun It'd be helpful to know where that's being thrown. I glanced through the code and see the exact same problem I described here [in Ask.js on line 50](https://github.com/SarasotaSun/koa-react-isomorphic-io-mongo-passport-master/blob/d37304d9ecc3e6d3195682da67f830f97b625bed/src/components/parts/Ask.js#L50) but I would think you would also see an issue with `this.setState` in this case.

Comment: Your clicked on a cached blob, if you go directly to the repo, you will see I made the change and the error points to the same line.

Comment: @SarasotaSun Another thing you can do to help is set your non-optional props' `propTypes` to `.isRequired` so that React will warn you ahead of time if a component doesn't receive a prop it should have.

Comment: @SarasotaSun No, I created that cached URL. As of now, that is still wrong on GitHub on the master branch.

Comment: No, I made the changes and can see them on the master

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91332/discussion-between-sarasota-sun-and-binarymuse).

Comment: @SarasotaSun The new answer is that you're not passing the `emit` property. https://github.com/SarasotaSun/koa-react-isomorphic-io-mongo-passport-master/blob/master/src/components/Speaker.js#L27 If you use `.isRequired` propTypes React should inform you of this when the component is rendered.

Comment: Yea I fixed that a few minutes ago already, but thanks. I am onto Ask.js now

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates `this` is null. The reason is react doesn't autobind `this` to the react element. That is, the `this` doesn't reference to the element itself while invoking `ask(question)` method. You only have to bind it in the [constructor](https://github.com/SarasotaSun/koa-react-isomorphic-io-mongo-passport-master/blob/master/src/components/parts/Questions.js#L11): `this.ask = this.ask.bind(this)`. It's better for you to read the ES6 class notes on [official react blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

Reading [react-router upgrade guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md) is also a good idea :)